# "this project contains resource errors, So aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures, fix resources problems first." In Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

> Blockquote

I am new in Android studio, I created a program and got resource error, please help me to fix this problem.

it shows  error that "This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failure. fix resource problem first.

please help me in solving this issue.

code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"


        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- Display whether Bluetooth is avilable or not-->
       <TextView

           android:id="@+id/statusBluetoothTv"

           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="14dp"
           android:minWidth=""
           android:text=" "

           android:textAlignment="center"
           android:textColor="#000"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

        <!--Bluetooth icon (on/off)-->

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/bluetoothIv"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
        <Button

            android:id="@+id/onBtn"
            android:minWidth="200dp"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Turn On"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />

        <!--off btn-->
        <Button

            android:id="@+id/offBtn"
            android:minWidth="200dp"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Turn Off"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />

        <!--Discoverable Button-->
        <Button

            android:id="@+id/DiscoverableBtn"
            android:minWidth="200dp"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Discover devices"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />

        <!--Get list of Paired devices button-->

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/pairedBtn"
            android:minWidth="200dp"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get paired Devices"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />

        <!--show paired devices here-->

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/pairedTv"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:minWidth="200dp"
           android:text=""
           android:textColor="#000" />
```

Comment: some thing problem with `resource` .Are you using svg ?

Comment: check your all xml layouts or any resource from drawable which may be causing this issue. if you can share the code i may help you.

Comment: @SanketPatel please help me

Comment: Does your AS point to a specific error or file? If u are using image/png/xml resources as image res or background, make sure they do exist in your drawable folder.

Comment: @AliEid it does not point to any specific error, and i am using the images already present on android studios.

Comment: Try adding your own images to test it. Use a single image in all places to check if this is the problem

Comment: if this xml you've shared is exact then close the imageview and linear layout. else try to remove styles for a while and test the code. check if your style is not using a resource which is not available or corrupted.

Comment: @SanketPatel if this was the issue, the compiler should have complained about them. I mean he may have posted them here wrongly

Comment: It is the exact code

Comment: did u try removing styles and tested the app? as i don't see any other issues in the layout that may cause you this error other than styles if they're old or incompatible.

Comment: @SanketPatel sir please help in my other question. i need help asap.

Comment: share the link of other question please

Comment: @SanketPatel bro, my error is solved, but now it shows new error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 76697 > 65536)

Comment: @SanketPatel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894076/error-incompatible-types-int-cannot-be-converted-to-string/59894912#59894912